# truncated LISTAGG string

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, aggregate-functions, oracle11gr2

I'm using Oracle 11g r2 and I need to concatenate strings (VARCHAR2, 300) from multiple rows. I'm using `LISTAGG` which works great until the concatenated string reaches the limit. At that point I receive a `ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long`.

In the end, I only want the first 4000 chars of the concatenated string. How I get there doesn't matter. I will accept inefficient solutions.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(T.NAME, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL)
FROM T
```

Comment: @Ben how can my question be a duplicate of the specified question, when it has been asked a few months AFTER mine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use the built-in (but deprecated) STRAGG function

```
    select sys.stragg(distinct name) from t
```

(please note that distinct seems to be necessary to avoid duplicates)

or define your own aggregation function / type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "STRING_AGG_TYPE" as object
(
  total varchar2(4000),

  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT string_agg_type) return number,

  member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self  IN OUT string_agg_type,
                                       value IN varchar2) return number,

  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self        IN string_agg_type,
                                         returnValue OUT varchar2,
                                         flags       IN number) return number,

  member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT string_agg_type,
                                     ctx2 IN string_agg_type) return number
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY "STRING_AGG_TYPE" is

  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT string_agg_type) return number is
  begin
    sctx := string_agg_type(null);
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;

  member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self  IN OUT string_agg_type,
                                       value IN varchar2) return number is
  begin
    -- prevent buffer overflow for more than 4,000 characters
    if nvl(length(self.total),
           0) + nvl(length(value),
                    0) < 4000 then
      self.total := self.total || ';' || value;
    end if;
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;

  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self        IN string_agg_type,
                                         returnValue OUT varchar2,
                                         flags       IN number) return number is
  begin
    returnValue := ltrim(self.total,
                         ';');
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;

  member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT string_agg_type,
                                     ctx2 IN string_agg_type) return number is
  begin
    self.total := self.total || ctx2.total;
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;

end;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stragg(input varchar2 )
   RETURN varchar2
   PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING string_agg_type;
```

and use it like this:

```
select STRAGG(name) from t
```

I believe this approach was orginally proposed by Tom Kyte (at least, that's where I got it from - [Asktom: StringAgg](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:229614022562)

Answer (score 4):

This code works for any length of data, fast enough

```
SELECT REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
           XMLAGG(
             XMLELEMENT("A",T.NAME)
           ORDER BY 1).getClobVal(),
         '<A>',''),
       '</A>','[delimiter]')
FROM T
```

Comment: This worked great for me with no problems about strings being too long.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help you:

```
substr(string, 1, 4000)
```

EDIT:

or try

```
SELECT [column], rtrim(
         xmlserialize(content 
           extract(
             xmlagg(xmlelement("n", (T.NAME||',') order by [column])
           , '//text()'
           )
         )
       , ','
       ) as list
FROM [table]
GROUP BY [column]
;
```

Comment: I've tried `substr(LISTAGG(T.NAME, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL), 1, 4000)` but I get the same error.
It seems, the error happens within the `LISTAGG` function

Comment: I edited my answer. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: I now get a different error: `ORA-22926: specified trim length is greater than current LOB value's length`.
I'm unsure where I can set the trim length, since neither `rtrim` nor `trim` has a length param.

Comment: How many rows you have got in your table?

Comment: Oh, It's a lot of. Do you need all rows?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need them. The resulting concatenated string can become quite huge.

Comment: Maybe You have to write more queries (id between 0 and 1000, id between 1000 and 2000, etc.), and use union all?

Answer (score 1):

This is the drawback of the LISTAGG function ,it does not handle the limit of the string generated due to  LISTAGG analytical function .For that you need to take the cumulative sum of length and based on that you need to limit .

```
worked out example on emp table 

select listagg(ename,' ')within group (order by null)
from
(
select ename,
         sum( length( ename ) + 1) 
            over ( order by ename rows between unbounded preceding and current row) length
 from emp

 )where lngth <= 4000
 ;
```

But this will not give the perfect result because if you look to the inner query ,it will generate a column with ename and its length as shown below

```
 ename      lenght 
===================
gaurav        6
rohan         11
:
:
garima        3996
anshoo        4002
=====================
```

So the above function will give you result till `garima` ....not till `ansh`,because listagg is based on the length column of inner query .